# "ERROR in : Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule " in ionic While building android app using "ionic cordova build android --prod" command

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { Geolocation } from "@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { IonicSelectableModule } from "ionic-selectable";
import { BatteryStatus } from "@ionic-native/battery-status/ngx";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { IonicStorageModule } from "@ionic/storage";
import { FilterPageModule } from "./pages/filter/filter.module";
import { NetworkInterface } from "@ionic-native/network-interface/ngx";
import { NgCalendarModule } from "ionic2-calendar";
import { ComponentsModule } from "./components/components.module";
import { FileOpener } from "@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx";
import { TextToSpeech } from "@ionic-native/text-to-speech/ngx";
import { AppMinimize } from "@ionic-native/app-minimize/ngx";
import { AppVersion } from "@ionic-native/app-version/ngx";
import { Market } from "@ionic-native/market/ngx";
import BackgroundGeolocation from "cordova-background-geolocation-lt";
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicSelectableModule,
    FilterPageModule,
    NgCalendarModule,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    BackgroundGeolocation,
    Geolocation,
    BatteryStatus,
    NetworkInterface,
    FileOpener,
    TextToSpeech,
    AppMinimize,
    AppVersion,
    Market,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ERROR in: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule in D:/new Demo/Example-Demo-mobile/Example-Demo-mobile/src/app/app.module.ts' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [StatusBar in D:/new Demo/Example-Demo-mobile/Example-Demo-mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx/index.d.ts, SplashScreen in D:/new Demo/Example-Demo-mobile/Example-Demo-mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx/index.d.ts, ?null?...]

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.